# how to convert date-time to epoch in python?

Tags: python, json, django, datetime, epoch

I want this particular date-time to be converted to epoch but it is giving me format error. what format should i use to do the following so that it can be json rendered. "2016-10-14 14:34:14+00:00". I am using python 2.7 and django 1.10

```
stra = "instance[0].Timing"
formata = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00"
timing = calendar.timegm(time.strptime(stra, formata))
     return HttpResponse(json.dumps(
           {'result': 'True'
            'timing': timing,
            }))
```

Comment: Post your code and the full error message please.

Comment: `stra` is already a string?

Comment: this is the error - time data 'instance[0].Timing' does not match format '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S+0000'

Comment: @KartikSharma Looks like something is already wrong in your previous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in django datetime object are converted in epoch as following way.

**Emample 1**

```
import datetime

current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
epoch = int(current_date.strftime("%s")) * 1000
```

**Example 2**

```
import datetime
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
epoch = int(date_object.strftime("%s")) * 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1, you can use `isoformat()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
# '2016-10-19T03:39:40.485521'
```

Option 2, `strftime()`, do not confuse it with `strptime`:

```
print(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00'))
# '2016-10-19 03:42:58+00:00'
```

Comment: I have this datetime with me(option 2) i want to convert this to epoch.

Answer (score 0):

This is a literal string, it's not pulling data out of whatever instance you have:

```
stra = "instance[0].Timing"
```

Perhaps you meant the following instead?

```
stra = instance[0].Timing
```